# add file to all branches of git

Tags: git, git-branch

Iam trying to add file in all branches of git :

```
cd <git url>
for remote in $(git branch); do
git checkout --track $remote
cp -r /path/of/file . #copy file from local to current directory
git add .
git commit -a -m "file added"
git push origin -u $remote
done
```

how to implement this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that - the question as asked isn't how git works, but you can add it and cherry-pick the commit to all branches which would do the same thing. Again: why?

Comment: Perhaps better to create the commit that add the file in one branch and then checkout the other branches one by one and cherry-pick the commit with its hash.

Comment: i want to keep one file in all branches as common, is there any other way like i want to keep abc.txt in all branches of my git repo !

Comment: You haven't answered why, and that's pretty important to understanding what you're doing.

Comment: and you can, by committing it to each branch, and cherry-picking or merging that initial commit and any subsequent changes from your 'master' branch to all your other ones.

Comment: @Philippe cherry pick holds true in this for loop logic ? if not what modifications needs to be done ?

Comment: @AD7six actually i want to have yml file in every branch so that i can use it for deployment by choosing respectice branch to deploy on azure devops

Comment: I suggest you do `git commit -a -m "make deployable"` and then cherry pick that to each branch. Unless you have 10s or 100s of branches there isn't any complexity to deal with - and if you do have - that info should be in the question. Please self-answer :).